Как сохранить маркер об валидности токена в asp.net core web api?
Создал достаточно простенький кастомный Identity Server. Запрос с клиента поступает на api, который отправляет аутентификационные данные на Identity Server, который уже, в свою очередь, выписывает токен аутентификации. Суть в том, что валидация токена должна происходить не на api, а не identity server'е. Тут стоит вопрос, как сказать, что бы api не отправлял токен на валидацию при каждом запросе, а что бы его сохранить на некий expiration time, после чего валидировать повторно?
Первое, что приходит на ум это кэш, но есть ли другие варианты такой реализации?
